# How to make a click over a button inside a dynamically loaded iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, firefox-addon, click

The title say it all. I am working with a iframe whose the only thing I know is part of their src attribute.  Until now I can reach the target element (an anchor) by their (known) id:

```
var f = $('iframe[src^="url"]', newTabBrowser.contentDocument);
if ( ! f.length)
    return;
var b = f.contents().find('#button'); 
if ( ! b.length)
    return;
```

At this point I have the desired anchor element into the jQuery variable `b`, but I can't click it. The anchor is like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="button" role="button" tabindex="0"></a>
```

I have tried:

```
b.click();
```

and:

```
simulateClick(b);

function simulateClick(elm) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    var canceled = !elm.dispatchEvent(evt);
    if(canceled) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

None of both works. Any idea about how to proceed or another technique to try?

OBS: This is part of a FF addon. That's why I use `newTabBrowser.contentDocument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var frame = $('#iframeID').get(0).contentDocument;
            $('#button', frame).click(function() {
                alert("Clicked me..!");
            });

        });
```

Hope it helps in some sense.

Comment: Your code bind a click event, I talk about trigger a click event. Should be `$('#button', frame).click()`. In any case my problem is due to a cross domains restrictions that violates the [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy ](Same origin policy) So your contributions is good and I accept it as that...